# So I have a local MySQL server and database. How do I take it online?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, obviously I am less than a beginner at this, any help is appreciated.

We have an assignment for school, and the plan is to have a node-red project(on different computers) connect to a MySQL database hosted on a server.

I have downloaded the MySQL server package, the ODBC and Workbench. All that jazz. The thing is that I can't find a way to make my server hosted anywhere else than on my localhost. As you can tell, I have never even touched servers or anything like that before, so I'm probably just missing something.

As far as I know, a server is just a PC hosting data for other PCs to access, so what do I have to do to just make my PC a server? I need my colleagues/partners to be able to connect to the database from their local machine, but since it's hosted on localhost, that is not possible. I have not found a way to just "put it online". I realise putting stuff online without any knowledge of what you're doing is not something you should do, but I really feel like I'm out of options here.

As I said, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must: (1) provide external access to your computer (real IP / port mapping / etc.) (2) create MySQL users with proper access rights which may access from needed (or all) hosts.

Comment: The short answer is that you don't. It's REALLY not a good idea to host something like this publicly on the Internet unless you understand what you are doing. @AnasOulahtak answer about using an existing hosting service is the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you host your database on a server online , try a free one for testing purposes, they are too many like :
https://remotemysql.com/
when you host your database you can access to it from any pc and also you can connect it with your PHP projects ex..